# How to send some list to another class and how to connect it

Tags: c#, asp.net

Im doing my HW to school, making some game.. i took blackjack bcs i thought its easy, but now i know that isnt easy for me.. So i need help with solution.

I tried to connect somehow the lists "cards", but idk if it is connected or not.

Here is shuffle

```
public class Shuffle
{
    public List<Card>cards;
    public void Michani()
    {
        Random ran = new Random();
        int r = cards.Count;
        while (r > 1)
        {
            int n = ran.Next();
            Card card = cards[n];
            cards[n] = cards[r];
            cards[r] = card;
        }
    }
}

public class Card
{      
    public CardValue Value { get; set; }
    public CardSuit Suit { get; set; }
    public int Weight { get; set; }
}

public enum CardValue : int
{
    Eso = 1,
    Dvojka = 2,
    Trojka = 3,
    Ctyrka = 4,
    Petka = 5,
    Sestka = 6,
    Sedmicka = 7,
    Osmicka = 8,
    Devitka = 9,
    Desitka = 10,
    Jack = 11,
    Queen = 12,
    King = 13,
}

public enum CardSuit : int
{
    Hearts = 1,
    Spades = 2,
    Clubs = 3,
    Diamons = 4
}
```

Here is ending card:

```
public class DeckGen
{
    public List<Card> cards;

    public void Deck()
    {
        for (int v = 0; v < 13; v++)
        {
            for (int s = 0; s < 4; s++)
            {
                cards.Add(new Card() { Suit = (CardSuit)s, Value = (CardValue)v });
                if (s <= 8)
                {
                    cards[cards.Count - 1].Weight = s + 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    cards[cards.Count - 1].Weight = 10;
                }

            };
        }

    }
}
```

Here is creating the deck:

```
public class DrawCard
{
    public List<Card> cards { get; }

    public Card Lizani()
    {
        if (cards.Count <= 0)
        {
            DeckGen();
            Shuffle();
        }
        Card returnedcard = cards[cards.Count - 1];
        cards.RemoveAt(cards.Count - 1);
        return returnedcard;
    }

    public void Shuffle()
    {

    }

    public void DeckGen()
    {

    }
}
```

Here is drawing a card:

Comment: It looks like you didn't quite include all of your example code. Could you add the "drawing a card" code?

Comment: Drawing card is actualy “Lizani”, you can see it on top of it.

Comment: You should edit the post to clarify that, then.

Comment: I turned pc off, so yesterday im gonna to Edit it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bunch of problems here, and a blog worthy of the best way to do this. But may i suggest and old fashioned (debatable) approach of just using and extension method

<sub>***Note*** i fixed bunch of mistakes</sub>

```
public static class CardUtils
{
   private static Random ran = new Random();
   public static void Shuffle(this List<Card> cards)
   {
      var n = cards.Count;
      while (n > 1)
      {
         n--;
         var k = ran.Next(n + 1);
         Card value = cards[k];
         cards[k] = cards[n];
         cards[n] = value;
      }
   }
}
```

**Usage**

```
chards.Shuffle();
```

<sub>***Note*** i say old fashioned as we tend not to use static classes like this these days for test-ability , and DI service. However, i think this is a nice simple solution and accessible everywhere you need it</sub>

<sub>***Also Note*** There are better randomization techniques, your players might get angsty because the shuffler isn't working that good</sub>

Comment: Oh thank you very much, if i got it, this is shuffle method, isnt it?

Comment: @JosefŠimůnek yes

Comment: Actually i think i have missed the point of the question,, However ill leave it here for a while. someone should be able to help you more soon

Comment: Nice, and the rest of code? Does it looks +- workable?

Comment: And can you help me, how to call it in data folder, its for ASP.NET, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know I did get the question truely or not but I think making the class and list static will do the trick and then you can call the list like

```
  DeckGen.CardList;
```